# Windows 10: Having issues (commands not readily available) with Powershell 7 + PSWindowsUpdate

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

setup:

- windows 10 2004 updates to latest stable updates
- powershell 7.0.3
- PSWindowsUpdate 2.2.0.2

**TLDR:** I am running the setup above and I cannot run the commands available in PSWindowsUpdate until I run "Get-Command -module PSWindowsUpdate".

---

I think it's best explained with an example.

```
> Install-WindowsUpdate

Install-WindowsUpdate: The term 'Install-WindowsUpdate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

> Get-Command -module PSWindowsUpdate

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           Clear-WUJob                                        2.2.0.2    PSWindowsUpdate
Alias           Download-WindowsUpdate                             2.2.0.2    PSWindowsUpdate
Alias           Get-WUInstall                                      2.2.0.2    PSWindowsUpdate
Alias           Get-WUList                                         2.2.0.2    PSWindowsUpdate
Alias           Hide-WindowsUpdate                                 2.2.0.2    PSWindowsUpdate
Alias           Install-WindowsUpdate                              2.2.0.2    PSWindowsUpdate
--snip--

> Install-WindowsUpdate
>
```

I installed the module via "Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force" and this created folders/files in $HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate.

As a test, I:

- move the "PSWindowsUpdate" folder from $HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Modules into C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules
- restart the PC
- rerun the command "Install-WindowsUpdate" (same issues as above)
- rerun the command "Get-Command -module PSWindowsUpdate"
- rerun the command "Install-WindowsUpdate" and now it's available

As another test, I:

- open a Powershell 5.x session/window
- install the PSWindowsUpdate module via "Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force"
- close the Powershell 5.x session/window
- open another Powershell 5.x session/window
- rerun the command "Install-WindowsUpdate"and no issues at all
- restart the PC
- rerun the command "Install-WindowsUpdate"and still no issues

Comment: For whatever reason on your host, that module is not being autoloaded. Just add it to your user profile(s) using the Import-Module cmdlet so that it is always loaded no matter what PowerShell instance you start.

Answer (score 1):

Just installing the module on the system is not enough, you must load the module into your session with `Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate`. A confusing feature here is that specifying `-Module` in your `Get-Command -Module PSWindowsUpdate` command actually runs `Import-Module` behind the scenes to check for commands within that module. For example, you can probably replicate this:

```
Get-Module AWSPowershell

# no output - module is not loaded

Get-Command -Module AWSPowershell

#  CommandType     Name                                               Version                   
#  -----------     ----                                               -------                  
#  Alias           Add-ALXBContactWithAddressBook                     3.3.590.0          
#  Alias           Add-ASInstances                                    3.3.590.0  
#  [etc]        

Get-Module AWSPowershell

#  ModuleType Version    Name                                     
#  ---------- -------    ----                              
#  Binary     3.3.590.0  awspowershell
```

Just installing the module is not enough per the `install-module` docs: "To prevent running modules that contain malicious code, installed modules are not automatically imported after installation."

Powershell has an environment variable to set your preference for this though: `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference`:

- **All:** Modules are imported automatically on first-use. To import a module, get or use any command in the module. For example, use Get-Command.
- **ModuleQualified:** Modules are imported automatically only when a user uses the module-qualified name of a command in the module. For example, if the user types MyModule\MyCommand, PowerShell imports the MyModule module.
- **None:** Automatic importing of modules is disabled in the session. To import a module, use the Import-Module cmdlet.

For more information about automatic importing of modules, see [about_Modules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: installing the module seems sufficient for Powershell 5.x though. Is that a bug/feature of Powershell 7.x?

Comment: @mrjayviper I've added some more information, but it doesn't seem like anything changed between powershell versions in this respect.